# Change color for specific functions

Tags: netbeans

I'm using assertions in my code, here is the example:

```
this.getNewLinkId = function() {
    var newLinkId = this.links.length + 1;
    console.assert(this.getLink(newLinkId).length === 0, 'Generated ID is already present within links!');
    return newLinkId;
};
```

But because of them the code may be slightly harder to read. Is there any way to specify the syntax highlight for `assert` functions? Make their color like that of comments, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that in NB. Maybe a strategic newline might help you though?

e.g.

```
this.getNewLinkId = function() {
    var newLinkId = this.links.length + 1;
    console.assert(this.getLink(newLinkId).length === 0, 
                   'Generated ID is already present within links!');
    return newLinkId;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice with new line!